# Tensorflow loss function no gradient error when provided with scalar

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

This question is about the tf.losses.huber_loss() function and how it can be applied on scalars rather than vectors. Thank you for your time!

My model is similar to a classification problem like MNIST. I based my code on the TensorFlow layers tutorial and made changes where I saw fit. I do not think the exact code is needed for my question.

I have lables that take integer values in {0,..,8}, that are converted into onehot labels like this:

```
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=n_classes)
```

The last layer in the model is

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense4, units=n_classes)
```

which is converted into predictions like this:

```
 predictions = {"classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1), "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")}
```

From the tutorial, I started with the tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy() loss function. But in my model, I am predicting in which discretized bin a value will fall. So I started looking for a loss function  that would translate that a prediction of one bin off is less of a problem than two bins off. Something like the absolute_difference or Huber function.

The code

```
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=n_classes)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
```

in combination with the optimizer:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=ps.learning_rate)
```

works without any errors. When changing to the Huber function:

```
loss = tf.losses.huber_loss(labels=onehot_labels, predictions=logits)
```

there are still no errors. But at this point I am unsure about what exactly happens. Based on the [reduction definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py) I expect that the Huber function is applied pairwise for elements of the vectors and then summed up or averaged.

I would like to apply the Huber function only on the label integer (in {0,...,9}) and predicted value:

```
preds = tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1)
```

So this is what I tried:

```
loss = tf.losses.huber_loss(labels=indices, predictions=preds)
```

This is raising the error

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable
```

I have found two common causes that I do not think are happening in my situation:

- [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511) where there is no path between tf.Variable objects and the loss function. But since my prediction code is often used and the labels were provided as integers, I do not think this applies here.
- The function is not derivable into a gradient. But the Huber function does work when vectors are used as input, so I do not think this is the case.

My question is: what code lets me use the Huber loss function on my two integer tensors (labels and predictions)?